# CannotAcquireLockException issue

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

My functionality is like i want to insert user address and user can have multiple addresses even user can mark one of it address as default address below is my code.
If user enter address and mark that address as default one we will reset other address default flag to false as show in code

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT, readOnly = false)
public Address store(Address address){
    Assert.notNull(address, "address can not be null");
    resetDefault(address);
    Address createdAddress = this.create(address);
    return createdAddress;
}
```

where

```
private void resetDefault(Address address) {
    if (address.isDefault())
        resetDefaultAddress(address);
}

 private void resetDefaultAddress(Address address) {
    addressRepository.unsetDefaultAddress(address.getAssociationId(),
            address.getCategory());
}
```

and we have used JPA repository

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Address a set a.defaultAddress = false where a.defaultAddress = true and a.associationId =:associationId and a.category =:category")
int unsetDefaultAddress(@Param("associationId") String associationId,
        @Param("category") AddressCategory category);
```

Now my issue is that it is working fine in developer environment but when we do load testing of our application where we done 100 concurrent request we are getting

```
org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into wsc_address (address1, address2, address3, alias, associationId, attributes, category, city, country, defaultaddress, email1, email2, firstname, lastaccesstimestamp, lastname, phone1, phone2, phone3, postalcode, province, status, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

We are using MySql database.

Or any single query which solve my purpose and improve performance.

I also notice that after comment out resetDefault(address); from store method it is working fine.

Comment: I also try with Isolation.READ_COMMITTED but still facing same issue.

Comment: Just a guess: do you have @Version field in your Address entity? Are you sure your test is not trying to save same Address entity with same version each time - in this case you supposed to get locking exception (OptimisticLockException in JPA).

Comment: No we do not have @Version field